# IEnumerable without data

Tags: c#, .net

If I have a method or a property that returns an `IEnumerable<SomeType>` that leads to no data,
is it more efficient to return an empty array `new SomeType[0]` or is it better to return an empty list `new List<SomeType>()` or is there an even better solution (IMO building an own type with generics could be such a solution but it seems to me a little bit overkill)?

The array is my favorite but what do you think about this?

Comment: Should be empty list because its safer for runtime.

Comment: @thethanghn: Can you explain what you mean by "safer for runtime"? An empty list is less safe than an empty array because *an empty list can be mutated to be empty no longer*. An empty array cannot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Return [`Enumerable.Empty<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx).

Comment: Better than creating a new object everytime the property is called.

Comment: I still find it strange that it is Enumerable.Empty<T>() rather than Enumerable<T>.Empty().

Comment: Maybe if it were "Enumerable<T>.Empty()" then the class constructor for Enumerable<T> would be called for each Type that is used (if not already initialized) and with "Enumerable.Empty<T>()" this could be prevented (only an idea, I don't have any profound knowledge of generics).